# NSArrayController setContent blocking main thread

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

In nib file I am binding arrayController to tableView and programmatically updating its content each time when I get array of data as

```
arrayController.content=someRecords;
```

But it consuming more time to set content (0.23 second for 1000 records) and blocking main thread. is there any known issue with array controller bindings? any other solution to effectively change the array controller content ?

Comment: Did you try using the same through bindings?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why its happening but in-spite of doing programmatically you can do the same through binding and also your code efforts will become less too, Follow the below steps:-

1) Inside your array controller binding inspector follow below attached screen shot
Also here yourArray is mutableArray

[image]

2) Now select your first tableView column and follow the below attached screen shot and similar way do for the other column as well

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your replay. As i mentioned in the question the arrayController is binded to the tableView and is working also. Only thing is iam changing the array controller content in code, this cause performance issues.